# Do contract/vendor developers need to be added to your developer account

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I work with a lot of contractors and vendors for mobile app development. They usually ask me to add them to my account and add their device IDs. If they have their own Apple Developer account, I don't think this is necessary. Are they be able to just use their own while developing?

We have an Enterprise account with Apple. We don't do the whole UDID exchange thing for test builds. We build for Enterprise distribution. (We do that because we have hundreds of test devices in geographically disperse locations.) I do give them those signing credentials. Is that enough for a developer to work with?

We deploy the apps ourselves so they don't need credentials for that. They can send us archives to sign.

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on what you want. Truly the developers id should be put under the company account for them to push and also do different security signing measures or app to app talking. However for the rather simple applications this is not necessary maybe around 70% of the time. Something else to think about is who is doing deployment, if you are having a developer or contractor do it for you then absolutely they need your account credentials. As for the device IDs there is no getting around that. You need to add their devices or buy them some because otherwise they are stuck developing on the simulator which does not at all simulate how the application will behave in real life for various reasons.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We do our own deployment, so that is not the issue. It's really about them developing on their own account because we cannot add their devices. We got the enterprise account when our regular account ran out of devices just from the in house folk who needed to test & approve the apps. Thanks for the response. I'll update the original question.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are responsible for submitting the app to the app store I can't think of a technical reason why developers should be unable to contribute to your app without being invited to join your developer program.

There may however be other concerns or limitations. For example being granted access as a "Member" role is a good way to confirm that you, the client, have accepted Apple's license agreements around pre-release software. Using a certificate issued by your organization to sign builds may also reduce the need to juggle app ids, particularly when testing in-app purchases, and therefore reduce the chance of mistakenly checking in such changes and confusing the team.